# Turbolinks + lightbox (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox, lightbox, turbolinks

I know this question has been asked to death but I still can't resolve things in my app. I'm running a rails 5 app (with turbolinks and the fancybox lightbox gem) and have some page-specific javascript to display images on model show pages:

application.html.erb

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <%= yield :page_scripts %>
</body>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% content_for :page_scripts do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
      $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
    })
  </script>
<% end %>
```

I still get the classic response whereby the image loads up nicely upon first page visit or page refresh. Navigating away and back again stops the lightbox from working (seems to just hang in my case).

How do I use the 'turbolinks:load' feature to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 3):

just use `{parent: 'body'}` and it will fix the issue with Turbolink.

```js
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({parent: 'body'});
```

[credit: Kirill Platonov](https://kirillplatonov.com/2014/08/10/rails-turbolinks-with-fancybox-2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change into below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
  })    
});
```

I hope this help you. You can go to details through this link [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads).

Comment: Hi Muhamad. I had tried that already and it doesn't help - still a case of it will work the first visit/refresh but not on subsequent visits. I'm not sure if it's anything to do with the loading of the images themselves - currently they are being loaded in from the public/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fully qualifies as an answer, but given that the scenario in this link was very similar:

https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1413

....I ended up following their advice and removing turbolinks from the show page using data-turbolinks="false".

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with tubolinks, but keep in mind that `$("a.fancybox").fancybox()` simply binds click event to current elements. So, you probably have to reattach it after navigating. Another possible solution would be to use event delegation using `selector` option, example (using v3.1):

```
$().fancybox({
  selector : '[data-fancybox="images"]',
  animationEffect : "fade"
});
```